# Serverless AWS schedule : ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

In serverless yml configuration, this is working

`events:
      - schedule: rate(24 hours)`

But, this is not

```
 `events:
  - schedule: cron(0 0 * * * *)`
```

nor this

```
 `events:
  - schedule: 
      rate : cron(0 0 * * * *)`
```

Comment: Did you mean to have backticks in your code sample?

Comment: No backticks in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `day-of-month` or `day-of-week` must be a question mark.

Which one doesn't matter in your case. Using the following expression should work for your case: `0 0 * * ? *`.

See the [CloudWatch Events documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) for more information and examples of cronschedules. Your specific case is actually mentioned there.

Comment: I need to run  cron job daily at 12 am.

Comment: I know, but you MUST have either day-of-week or day-of-month be a question mark. E.g. `0 0 * * ? *`.